# Understanding JavaScript hoisting and truthy & falsy

Tags: javascript, type-coercion, truthiness, hoisting

I've been reading about JavaScript hoisting sometime back.

[JavaScript Scoping and Hoisting by Ben Cherry](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting) 
[Two words about “hoisting” by Dmitry Soshnikov](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/notes/note-4-two-words-about-hoisting/)

and, some more about JavaScript type-coercion, truth & false test:
[Truth, Equality and JavaScript](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/) and some other resource

And while practicing some, and found I m missing some important concept about the hoisting and a variable' truthy & falsy.

## 1: 'if' truth test with duplicate variable declaration

```
var foo = 1; 
function bar() { 
    if (!foo) { 
    alert('inside if');
        var foo = 10; 
    } 

} 
bar();
```

o/p: `inside if`

**Doubt:** 'foo' value being '1', `if(!foo)` should evaluates to `false` and that block should not be executed (quoting from above resources: hoisting affects only the `var` & `function` declaration, but not the execution). But why is that alert is shown.
This is not the case if I directly use `false` (shown in the below no-tricks code: snippet #3)

## 2: 'if' truth test without duplicate variable declaration

```
var foo = 1; 
function bar() { 
    if (!foo) { 
        alert('inside if');
    } 

} 
bar();
```

o/p: *no output; means control not entered 'if' block*
This is what one could expect

## 3: 'if' using 'false' with duplicate variable declaration

```
var foo = 1; 
function bar() { 
    if (false) { 
        alert('inside if');
        var foo = 10; 
    } 
} 
bar();
```

o/p: *no output; means control not entered 'if' block*
This is what one could expect

Someone please clarify. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For your example number 1, the alert is shown because you're using `var` inside the function and the `var` declaration is hoisted to the top of the function, so it is equivalent to:

---

```
var foo = 1; 
function bar() {
    var foo;
    if (!foo) {
        alert('inside if');
        foo = 10; 
    } 

} 
bar();
```

One might conclude that these sorts of issues offer compelling reason to declare all variables explicitly at the top of the function.

Comment: My bad. I didn't mind the function at all. I m only concentrating on the type coercion and hoisting (they are revolving in my head). If the duplicate declaration is not inside a function, then 'foo' will have the previous value (1) even after the second declaration. This all thinking made me to miss the function used. Thanks for opening my eye :)

Comment: Why doesen't number three work then? if a variable is undefined doesent it mean its false?

Answer (score 1):

Only variable *declaration* is eagerly evaluated. The variable assignment in your first case (in the `if` block) occurs only upon entering the `if` block.

The variable you only *declare*, but not assign any value to, has the value of `undefined` (which coerces to `false`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @patrick dw and You both answered it correct (in fact thanks for ignoring my ignorance). But I can only accept only one answer and as Mr. Patrick answered first I've accepted his. By the way I've 'Up'ed your answer too. Thanks.