# Why is there no comparison statement in this javascript 'If... Else...' statement

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, if-statement

In the following code

```
var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow IMG:first');
```

the part '$active.next().length' doesn't seem to compare anything and I don't understand how the condition is determined to be True or False.

Or is it saying that:
if the various $next is equal to $active.next().length then the condition is true?

Comment: you might wanna read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766044/understanding-javascript-hoisting-and-truthy-falsy

Comment: A funkier (and shorter and less function calls) way of doing this would be var $next = $($active.next()[0] || '#slideshow img:first');

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In javascript any expression can be converted to a truthy or falsy value and hence is valid in a comparison place.  The values which are false in javascript are

- `false`
- `0`
- `""` (empty string)
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `NaN`

In this case `length` refers to a numeric value and if it evaluates to `0` then it will be considered falsy.  Otherwise it will be truthy

Answer (score 5):

If the `length` property is equal to `0` or `undefined` (i.e. `$active` is not an array), the condition will be `false`.

Answer (score 2):

If `$active.next().length` is `true`, which means that there is a next element, then `$next = $active.next()`. Otherwise `$next = $('#slideshow IMG:first')`. The `?` operator is called the ternary operator. It is a short `if else`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a ternary comparison equivalent to:

```
if($active.next().length) {
    $next = $active.next();
}
else {
    $next = $('#slideshow IMG:first');
}
```

So the condition is based on $active.next().length which should return a value of zero or greater. Anything greater than zero, JavaScript will interpret as true, zero false.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking at a [Ternary opertation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) which is a short hand for If... Else... has you mentioned in the title.

So the long version of your statement is;

```
if($active.next().length){
 $next = $active.next();
}else {
 $next = $('#slideshow IMG:first');
}
```