# Access variable in if block

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
var func = function () {
   var i: number = 0;
   if (i == 0) {
      var y: number = 1;
   }

   document.body.innerHTML = y.toString(); // js/ts should complain me in this line
};

func(); // output: 1
```

As you can see, I've declared variable `y` inside `if` block. So, I think it couldn't be referenced outside the scope.

But, when I've tried to run the code, the output is `1`.

Is it an issue in typescript/javascript?

Comment: No, it is by design.

Comment: `var` in `if` is scoped to the function not the if.

Comment: I don't think typescript differs from javascript here, and `var` has function scope. Use `let` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding JavaScript hoisting and truthy & falsy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766044/understanding-javascript-hoisting-and-truthy-falsy)

Comment: @HarpreetSingh How duplicate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variables in Javascript are [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), meaning that `var y` is moved to the top of the function as if it were declared there.

Initialization, however is not hoisted, so if you change `i` to be something other than `0`, the variable `y` will still exist, but it will have the value `undefined`.

This means that the function is exactly equivalent to:

```
var func = function () {
   var i: number = 0;
   var y: number;
   if (i == 0) {
       y = 1;
   }

   document.body.innerHTML = y.toString(); // js/ts should complain me in this line
};
```

To get the behavior you expect, you need to use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), which is a part of ECMAScript 2015 (ES6). It is block scoped, as you expect. It will also effectively work so that it is accessible only from the point of definition onwards, which is also probably as you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

If you re-declare a JavaScript variable, it will not lose its value.

The second reference might pave way for a new variable syntax. Actually if you recall variable declaration is not neccessary in javascript. Simpe

y=1;

also works.

The second time when you reference y, outside if block, in my opinion, it tries a re-declaration and retains the old value.

Reference - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp
& http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has function scope afaik. Any variable declared within a function, should be accessible from anywhere within the function. So, if you have a function checking if i==0, then you can achieve what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

This is as it is supposed to be. Javascript scopes by function, not by block. (This does make it unlike many popular languages)

Variables declared like `var myVar = 10;` will seep into nested functions but not the other way around. Variables declared like `myVar = 10;` will go global.

I couldn't find anything which suggested that typescript was any different.

Answer (score 1):

Variables declared inside of an `if` statement are not scoped to the `if` statement. They're scoped to the current execution context. There's the Global execution context and then when a function is run, it creates it's own execution context. Inside of your function, you created the variables `y` and `i`. It doesn't matter that `y` was created inside of the `if` statement, because once it runs, `y` is created in the scope of the function. So then you do `y.toString()`, which can access `y` because it's scoped to the function not the if statement. That's why you get the output of `1`. This is not an error, it's by design.